# How to make check and disable the option in listbox based on the supplied values in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

Hi I am developing one web application. I have one `listbox` with options. I am binding values from database.

On page load some of the options I want to make *checked* and *disable* based on values supplied.

This is my listbox.

```html
<b>Awarded To:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlvendors" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" class="limitedNumbSelect2"></asp:ListBox>
```

I am pushing values to array based on some calculations.

```js
var users = [];
$('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="CheckBox"]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("disabled") == true)
    users.push($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text().trim());
});
test(users);

//This is my function to disable and make checked listbox options.

function test(users) {
  alert("users:" + users)
  var a, b;
  $(".limitedNumbSelect2 option").each(function() {
    debugger;
    b = $(this).val();
    $.each(users, function(index, value) {
      var a = users[index];
      //logic to disable options
    });
  });
}
```

For example if my users array contains *test1,test2* then corresponding options in the `listbox(test1,test2)` i want to disable and make checked. My problem is i am not able to loop through the options in the below line.

```
$(".limitedNumbSelect2 option").each(function ()
```

This is i tried below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        disableoptions1();
    });
    function disableoptions1() {
    var users = $('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="CheckBox"]:disabled').map(function () {
        return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text().trim();
    }).get();
        test(users);
        function test(users) {
        $(".limitedNumbSelect2 option").filter(function () {
            return users.indexOf(this.value) != -1;
        }).prop({
            selected: true,
            disabled: true
        });
    }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you can simplify your code which builds the `users` array by using `map()` and the `:disabled` selector:

```
var users = $('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="CheckBox"]:disabled').map(function () {
  return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text().trim();
}).get();
test(users);
```

From there you can use `each()` to loop through the `option` elements and compare their values to those in the array:

```
$(".limitedNumbSelect2 option").each(function() {
  if (users.indexOf(this.value) != -1) {
    $(this).prop({
      selected: true,
      disabled: true
    });
  }
});
```

Alternatively you could use `filter()` to achieve the same result:

```
$(".limitedNumbSelect2 option").filter(function() {
  return users.indexOf(this.value) != -1;
}).prop({
  selected: true,
  disabled: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will get required values in users variable. But my $(".limitedNumbSelect2 option").filter(function() not working. I will update what i tried.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could update the question with the HTML that's generated as the ASP ListBox control isn't relevant to the question itself

Comment: Thank you. this.value will be holding id instead of value. So this may be the problem?

Comment: Ah ok, then yes you need to use whatever attribute of the checkbox which is held in the array. If it's the `id`, you can use `this.id` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, using this you Iterate `users` array,
use `.prop()` or `.attr()`

```
$.each(users, function (index, value) {
    var a = users[index];
    //logic to disable options
    $(".limitedNumbSelect2 option[value="+a+"]").attr("selected", true);
    $(".limitedNumbSelect2 option[value="+a+"]").attr("disabled", true);
});
```